# Show with the direct Comparison Test that $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq\theta$ converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, absolute-convergence

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}{a_n}$ be an infinite series of real numbers. There is a $\theta$ with $0<\theta<1$ and a $n_0 > 0$, so $$\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\leq\theta$$ for all $n \ge n_0$. Show that the series converges absolutely.

So I need verification here. Quite funny, because this is the first task out of many and I am certain that the other ones are correct, but this one I am not sure of.

My proof feels wrong, it feels like as if it is way too short.

My proof here:

Since $\lvert a_{n} \rvert \leq \theta$ and $\theta \in (0,1)$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}{a_n}$ converges. And also since $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}≤a_n$, the series converges absolutely.

Comment: $|a_n| \le \theta^n$

Comment: I don't see why $0\le |a_n| \le \theta <1$ implies the series converges. Anyway, the hypothesis is $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\le \theta$, not $|a_n|\le \theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\le \theta\to 0\le |a_n|\le \theta^n$$therefore $$0\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|\le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\theta ^n={\theta\over 1-\theta}$$which completes the proof.

Comment: How do you conclude that it equals $1/1-\theta$ at the end?

Comment: I simply used Geometric Sum (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Answer (score 1):

We are told that $|a_n|^{\frac1n}\leq \theta$ whenever $n \geq n_0$. So if $n \geq n_0$, it then follows that we have $0\leq |a_n|\leq\theta^n$. Since $\theta \in (0,1)$, it also follows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \theta^n$ is a convergent geometric series. Now the comparison test seems relevant...

Always check to make sure you are using the hypotheses of the problem, otherwise things tend to go agley.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt[n]{\mid a_n\mid}\lt\theta\implies \mid a_n\mid\le\theta ^n\implies \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mid a_n\mid\le\sum_{n=0}^\infty\theta^n=\frac 1{1-\theta}\lt\infty $, since $\theta \lt1$.

Thus the series converges absolutely by comparison with a geometric series.

Comment: How do you conclude that it equals $1/1-\theta$ at the end?

Comment: $(1-\theta)(1+\theta+\theta^2+\dots+\theta ^n)=1-\theta ^{n+1}$.  Divide both sides by $(1-\theta) $ and let $n\to\infty$.  This is known as "telescoping", because of all the cancellation.